# How do you change the state of an image on a TFT display when the associated pin changes state?

Tags: programming, display

I just recently resolved my problem on getting images to load on to my TFT display via the SD card. Thanks to UTFT_SdRaw!!! it's by far the easiest to use. For a novice like me, its been a real feat. Now translating the code, I am trying to turn on and off the image when the pin state changes:

Example:
When pin A2 on my MEGA goes high (+5vdc) I want my SD to spool up and load an image so here is my code snipit:

****myFiles.load(20, 55, 130, 130, "Power Medium.raw");****

So now when the pin state changes back to low (0vdc), how do I remove the image without clearing the entire screen? The image seems to stay frozen instead of disappearing when the pin voltage falls away.

Any ideas? I am stumped. Thanks in advance for any comments and suggestions that may help me over the hump.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite silmple: just draw a box over the image the same colour as the background.

Either that or draw a different image over the top of the existing image.